# Roku BrightScript HdListItemIconSelectedUrl clipped

Tags: roku, brightscript, labellist

I'm trying to display an image on an item in a [LabelList](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/labellist.md#data-bindings).  I've set the `HDLISTITEMICONSELECTEDURL` field to an image in my images folder.  At runtime, this results in the image clipped on the left.  I'm using a 16x16 png image.  I've set the text alignment to Center.

How can I display the full image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by replacing the LabelList with a [ButtonGroup](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/layout-group-nodes/buttongroup.md).  This allowed me to set the `IconUri` and `focusedIconUri` fields to the appropriate image fields.